# one filter criteria, two files

Tags: file, unix, awk, data-cleaning

I have a file which looks something like this

```
VAR1    VAR2    VAR3    VAR4
ID1     foo     0.1     0.1
ID2     foo     1       1
ID3     foo     foo     .
ID4     foo     foo     foo
ID5     foo     .       1
ID6     foo     -0.1    -0.1
ID7     foo     -1      -1
ID8     foo     5e-08   5e-08
```

I want to filter out rows based on a sequential set of criteria (e.g. first remove all non-numeric entries from column 3, then all negative from column 4) but I want to save all rows that meet these intermediate criteria. That is, my final output should be 1) a file containing all rows that were removed during the first step, 2) a file containg all rows that were removed during the next step, and 3) a file containing all rows that survived the filtering.

What I got so far is:

```
awk '$3!=$3*1  {print}' < file.txt > REMOVED_COL_3.txt
if [[ $( find REMOVED_COL_3.txt -type f -size +0c 2>/dev/null ) ]]
then
awk '$3==$3*1' < file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
fi
awk '$4<0 {print}' < file.txt > REMOVED_COL_4.txt
if [[ $( find REMOVED_COL_4.txt -type f -size +0c 2>/dev/null ) ]]
then
awk '$4>=0 {print}' < file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
fi
```

Which works, but takes a lot of time in my real dataset (~13 million rows prefiltered).

Is it possible to `awk` once and have it save the rows that meet the criteria in one file and those that do not in another file? Or something else?

EDIT:
I forgot the header in my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very possible in a single awk script. You can use `if/else if/else` in `awk` as well as redirect your individual `print` statements to different files:

```
awk '{ if ($3!=$3*1) {print $0 > "REMOVED_COL_3.txt"} else if ($4<0) {print $0 > "REMOVED_COL_4.txt"} else {print $0 > "everythingelse_out.txt"}}' file.txt && mv -f everythingelse_out.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the header of my initial file. Would it also be possible to save that to all the output files?

Comment: Yes. You could add (at the beginning) `NR==1{print $0>"REMOVED_COL_3.txt"; print $0>"REMOVED_COL_4.txt"; print $0>"everythingelse_out.txt"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
NR==1 {
    split("REMOVED_COL_3.txt REMOVED_COL_4.txt tmp.txt",outfiles)
    for (outnr in outfiles) {
        print > outfiles[outnr]
    }
    next
}
{
    if ($3 != $3+0)  { outnr=1 }
    else if ($4 < 0) { outnr=2 }
    else             { outnr=3 }
    print > outfiles[outnr]
}
' file.txt &&
mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

I used `$3+0` instead of `$3*1` to convert the string to a number since addition is usually a little faster than multiplication and it's the more common way of performing that action, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Conversion: `To force a string to be converted to a number, add zero to that string.`

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the header of my initial file. Would it also be possible to save that to all the output files?